# Returning adjacent keys from a TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

Given the following `TreeMap`:

```
Map<Double, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Double, Integer>() {{. 
        put("52.1", 1);
        put("53.4", 2); 
        put("57.1", 3); 
        put("59.4", 7); 
        put("60.2", 11); 
        put("71.6", 16)}};
```

What would be the best way to return the closest n matches (in both directions) for a given double? For instance, n=2 and "58.0" would return 53.4, 57.1, 59.4, 60.2

Comment: Have a look at `lowerEntry()` and `higherEntry()` and simple for-loops

Comment: Or `headMap()` and `tailMap()`. Look over the [NavigableMap API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), there are lots of options.

Comment: A key part to make the extended methods of `NavigableMap` work is conversion of the `String` data (e.g., "53.4") to a `Double` instance. Your code doesn't illustrate that. Can you please include your actual, compilable code, so that we can help address any issues there? As an aside, you are using [double-brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/3474) here, which I would strongly discourage.

Comment: Pun not intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
new TreeMap <>(
        Map.of(
                52.1d , 1 ,
                53.4d , 2 ,
                57.1d , 3 ,
                59.4d , 7 ,
                60.2d , 11 ,
                71.6d , 16
        )
)
.floorKey( 58.0d )     // Or call `.ceilingKey( 58.0d )`
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/AvBlmu).

> 57.1

## `NavigableMap::lowerKey/higherKey`

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a `NavigableMap`.

The [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface provides methods for retrieving adjacent keys (and entries).

- [`lowerKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#lowerKey(K))
- [`higherKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherKey(K))

Repeat the commands to fetch as many adjacent keys as you desire, until receiving a `null`.

## Comparing keys

On second reading, it seems you do not have a key. You have a value you want to compare to keys in a map.

In this case, fetch a `Set` of all the keys in the map. `NavigableMap` extends `SortedMap`. So we can call [`SortedMap::keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet()). The returned set iterates in sorted order.

```
Set< Double > set = map.keySet() ;
```

Make a `List` of that, to access individual elements by index.

```
List< Double > doublesListSorted = List.of( set.toArray() ) ;  // Get un-modifiable list.
```

Now you can loop the sorted list to compare values.

### `NavigableMap::floorKey/ceilingKey`

Or, as [dnault commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919948/returning-adjacent-keys-from-a-treemap/62920278?noredirect=1#comment111268882_62920278), we can ask the `NavigableMap` to compare key values for a nearest-match.

- [`floorKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorKey(K))
  Returns the greatest key less than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key.
- [`ceilingKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingKey(K))
  Returns the least key greater than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key.

## Example code

Make an input map. We use [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)) initially for its convenient literal syntax. Then we feed that [un-modifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) to the constructor of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Map)). Our literal input seen here happens to be sorted, but that is irrelevant, as the `TreeMap` constructor will sort the entries by key.

```java
NavigableMap < Double, Integer > map =
        new TreeMap <>(
                Map.of(
                        52.1d , 1 ,
                        53.4d , 2 ,
                        57.1d , 3 ,
                        59.4d , 7 ,
                        60.2d , 11 ,
                        71.6d , 16
                )
        );
```

> map.toString(): {52.1=1, 53.4=2, 57.1=3, 59.4=7, 60.2=11, 71.6=16}

Set our target to which we want the closest matches.

```java
Double target = 58.0d;
```

Get the adjacent keys, next lower, and next higher.

```java
Double nextLower = map.floorKey( target );
Double nextHigher = map.ceilingKey( target );
```

> nextLower = 57.1
> nextHigher = 59.4

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/AvBlmu)

---

Notes:

- As [commented by erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919948/returning-adjacent-keys-from-a-treemap/62920278?noredirect=1#comment111268307_62919948) your double-brace initialization is something of a hack. Now unnecessary given the new `List.of` literal syntax shown in this Answer.
- If you care about [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) rather than [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html).

---

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Comment: I appreciate (and yes up-voted) the help. I was using lowerkey and higherkey but it seemed a little kludgy. I like the SortedMap solution.

Comment: Instead of looping over the keyset to compare keys, you can call [ceilingKey(K key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingKey-K-) or [floorKey(K key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorKey-K-) to get the keys nearest any given starting point.

Comment: @dnault Thank you for the tip. That makes for slick simple coding.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this in loop form. I was attempting to find n values below and above a given value for interpolation.